# Pytest-Django Database access not allowed error when importing a form

Tags: python, django, pytest, pytest-django

I've been having a problem trying to run some tests using Pytest in Django.

I've been trying to test some forms, and I've just started by importing pytest and then from the forms file imported the form to be tested.

The form in question has a MultipleChoiceField with a choices parameter that gets populated by querying the database for some options.

So it's something like this:

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_choices_from_db())
```

where get_choices_from_db returns a [(choice.id, choice.name) for choice in queryset] for some query set.

My test is still non-existant, I've just written this:

```py
import pytest
from project.forms import MyForm

@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_my_form() -> None:
    pass
```

and it breaks with the following error:

" RuntimeError: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it."
and a stack trace which complains about the form class at the line where it has to access the db to get the choices.

I've seen a couple of similar cases around, like:
[pytest-django won't allow database access even with mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56389216/pytest-django-wont-allow-database-access-even-with-mark)
or [Django pytest database access for data migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697215/django-pytest-database-access-for-data-migration/37704920#37704920)
but I did not really understand the solution.

Why would pytest instantiate the form at import time? Isn't it supposed to do such instantiations inside the test, as some might require db access?
The first solution talks about a migration that creates groups with permissions, which I didn't really undestand, as I don't know much about django migrations yet, but if it was relevant, I didn't understand how.

Does anyone has any ideas/suggestions about this?

Update: Importing the form inside the test function seems to work fine, but I wonder why would it try to instantiate the form on import? How does this work?

Answer (score 0):

A colleague helped me with the answer, so I'll post it just in case someone has the same issue:

During import the whole file is read. In order to run the function just once at the form instantiation time, the choices part of

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_choices_from_db())
```

should turn to

```py
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_choices=forms.MultipleChoiceField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.fields["my_choices"].choices = get_choices_from_db()
```

This should only access the db when the form is instantiated.